# 13.04 installed on Parallels on OSX. Very slow graphics performance

Tags: unity, 13.04, macosx, parallels

I installed 13.04 on my MacBook Pro running Parallels.
Everything works pretty well but when showing and hiding windows the performance is very slow.
I read around a bit.

I'm running 64 bit, 3.9 GiB memory, Intel® Core™ i7 CPU M 620 @ 2.67GHz

I ran `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` and got:

```
Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Older solutions to this problem for previous (12.xx) versions do not apply here since there appear to be no unity controls in the system settings.

So my question is this. What do I need to do to get these window fades to speed up or how do I simply turn off this somewhat redundant feature without screwing other stuff up?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Additionally in the VM configuration under Hardware -> video it is set to 64meg video memory with 3d acceleration ON and Vertical synchronisation ON. I tried switching off the 3d acceleration but to no effect.

Comment: Perhaps you ought to use `Oracle VirtualBox` (open-source) or `VMWare Fusion` (fast and powerful) instead...

Comment: As it happens this problem also occurs with VirtualBox, though there is a fix for that. In fact this appears to be a fairly common issue dating back to 12.xx versions of Ubuntu. So rather than rip out my entire configuration and put in a different one only to find that I still have the same problem I would prefer to find a fix for this configuration, and possibly help those who have also chosen this road.

Comment: I'm actually a little surprised that a Linux distro doesn't have a way to turn off extraneous animation to improve performance. Is this for real? Performance is otherwise OK given the circumstances. If I could turn off this annoying sloth with the windows it would be no big deal.

Comment: Well, with Linux distros there is ALWAYS a way, its just that sometimes the way is extremely involved.

Comment: Now we understand one another. I understand for example that one way is to strip out Unity and replace it with Gnome, but then why would I do that when I can install some other distro? I mean, wahey! What am I doing here? I'm not really a Linux noob but not really an adherent either. I'm doing this because I keep testing the option of departing from the other alternatives, but it has to be workable, and the ability to turn off silly things like animated windows is one of the reasons one wishes for an alternative.

Comment: Now we are wildly off topic, so let us return there. Is it true that there really is no way to make Unity NOT do fades and scaling which can cause problems with cards or configs of lesser greatness?

Comment: There's always edit and recompile, although I'm sure there's likely a setting somewhere in `dconf`.

Answer (score 0):

Parallels 9 for Mac OS X: In the settings of virtual machine (VM must be shut down), go to Hardware -> Video -> 3D acceleration (On) and start your VM:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Parallels and NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: Parallels using NVIDIA GeForce 320M OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string:  2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.19 310.90.10.05b12

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Answer (score -1):

Now Unity 3D is working on my MacBook Pro.

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on Parallels Version **8.0.18608** (Revision 898384; Wed, 17 Jul 2013).

Here an output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` command:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Parallels and NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: Parallels using NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string:  2.1 NVIDIA-8.12.47 310.40.00.05f01

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Try to upgrade your Parallels version, it should work.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se], please include details about how you solved the problem.

Comment: I just installed the new Parallels version and now it works as described above.